# should new users be reminded to accept answers?

Tags: discussion

(At the risk of sounding like someone overly concerned with her reputation...)

Should new users be reminded to accept answers?  In this question - [Rewriting a query and eliminating subqueries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18327/rewriting-a-query-and-eliminating-subqueries) - the asker, who is a newbie, seems to indicate the solution works.

Comment: Please click the checkmark below the voting arrows on the "most correct answer" if one or more solves the problem at hand. This lets others know that you have found your solution, so they won't keep trying to solve an already solved problem. It also let's future users (who may find this same question through Google or Bing, etc) to know what the solution was and move on more quickly with their day, instead of having to troubleshoot each given answer. In addition to checking off accepts, we also encourage upvoting for helpful answers. Thanks again! See the [FAQ#howtoask] for more.

Comment: PS: that was so that it was evident how it looks, if you just copy and paste my block in quickly

Comment: Can/should mods be allowed to mark them as the answer when they see something like this?  I guess that is an extension of the question.

Comment: @jgardner04 That's been discussed before on Meta.SO, and the answer is a resounding **NO**.  The only person that can or should be able to mark an answer as correct is the OP.  Anyone else is just guessing for the most part.  There's nothing stopping us from opening a similar/related question and putting the canonical answer in there, though.

Comment: @JNK I'm ok with that.  I just didn't know if my comment was a natural extension of the OP question.

Comment: Hint, you may want to check accept :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be shy, but don't be rude either. Not all users always understand how the system works here, so it's always an encouragement to approach with a gentle reminder to

> Please click the checkmark below the voting arrows on the "most correct answer" if one or more solves the problem at hand. This lets others know that you have found your solution, so they won't keep trying to solve an already solved problem. It also let's future users (who may find this same question through Google or Bing, etc) to know what the solution was and move on more quickly with their day, instead of having to troubleshoot each given answer. In addition to checking off accepts, we also encourage upvoting for helpful answers. Thanks again! See the [FAQ#howtoask] for more.

Or something to that effect.

Comment: Nice - I may steal this verbatim!  :)

Comment: @JHFB there's a [user script to store pro forma comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) you can use for things like this too.

Comment: Notice that I added a slight tweak to my previous comment, and updated the one on the Q. Also, JNK is right with the userscript, I just tend to get all old fashioned and type it out everytime.

Comment: The finger exercise keeps you young!